# PyMongo: BSON to JSON dict conversion (dumps returns a JSON string)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, bson

Snippet that fetches records from MongoDB using pymongo client

```
from bson.json_util import dumps

cursor = db.collections.find({"Test": "Sample"})

for msg in cursor:
    json_msg = dumps(msg)
```

However, the json_msg is of type string. Is there a way to get JSON object which can be traversed in something like a dict? I want to process the retrieved JSON objects while traversing through them.

I tried `json.loads(json_msg)` , but that converts the json_msg back to BSON format again.

Edit: I am not looking to just print (which is possible by printing string); however, to iterate and process the JSON object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value returned from `collections.find` is already a Python dict, which you can iterate. `dumps` will convert it to a string; so don't dump it, just use it.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't using the correct nested key to access the fields.